# Shrink a Calendar

Tags: asp.net, .net

I have a calendar object on my ASPX page, and all works well, until my user asked for it to be smaller.

I tried setting the hieght and width. but it wouldn't reduce the calendar from the default size, it would however, increase the size if I made them bigger than the default.  Am I just stuck with the default size being the smallest it gets?

Thanks

Comment: Are you referring to the Calendar control [`<asp:Calendar />`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.calendar.aspx)?

Comment: @jrummell: yes, thats the one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another answer 5 minutes after I ask...always the way.

The problem of shinking is all in the font size.  It won't shrink the font automatically to fit a smaller calendar.  So I just used CSS to do so:

```
font:12px arial,tahoma,sans-serif;
```

and it would finally shrink down.